# What's the difference between starting nginx with command "nginx", "service start nginx" and "systemctl nginx start"?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have noticed that when ever I start nginx with ubuntu command "nginx" and I do systemctl status nginx. It shows that systemctl is disabled. More over if I first start nginx with command systemctl start nginx and i try to start nginx with command nginx, it check the availbility of the ports and then says nginx: [emerg] still could not bind(). So i thought there must be a differene and their purpose. When I strt nginx with command nginx the only way to stop nginx is by the means of force using killlall nginx or kill -9 (process id) or by clearing the port. So I am pretty sure there is some difference in them.

Comment: Not only got confused by nginx. I think you maybe confused by all processes that could be managed by systemctl and native command script. You should get some knowledge about `systemctl`, do not focus on nginx.

Comment: Thnks it helped me a lot but still its not clear why it is possible to start a process saperately with these two commands. That was the main reason I asked this question is the first place, nginx and systemctl start nginx if one is used and then it also tried to start the same demon with other command why? Thx for reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the examples you have provied is how the processes are being started.

Running the command `nginx` will start the application and wait for your user action to stop it.

The `systemctl` or `service` commands are nearly the same thing and running `service nginx start` or `systemctl start nginx` will start a service in the background running the Nginx daemon.

You can also use this to do a `service nginx restart` or `systemctl restart nginx` to restart the service, or even a `service nginx reload` / `systemctl reload nginx` to reload the configuration without completely stopping the Nginx server.

The reason why you can't do both `nginx` and `systemctl start nginx` is due to the nginx configuration already listening port 80, and you can't listen on the same port on a single IP address at the same time.

You can also force the nginx service to start on boot by running `systemctl enable nginx` which will be why your `systemctl status nginx` returns 'disabled'.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes it did helped a lot. Thnks can you also pls ans that why of nginx is already running with command nginx and why is that it is possible to start it with command systemctl start nginx? I mean if its already running why the system even attempts to start again?

Comment: This is due to the fact that the computer will only perform the tasks it's told to do. So if you tell it to start nginx, it will start nginx for you and run into an error once it has failed to bind the ports.

Comment: Perhaps there is nothing to check as the command to execute the programs gets run , to check if the program can even run or not and hence it actually attempts to run the program. So now I am clear. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

`service` command is just a simple script which basically abstract choosing the underlying init system (upstart, systemmd , /etc/init.d or *systemctl*).

since it being a very concise script, it only supports a very limited set of operations (start | stop | reload .. ).

However, if you actually want to perform the additional operation you need to make use of the actual init system in this case systemctl

An apt example would be starting the service on boot time using systemctl `sudo systemctl enable the-name-of-service` which is not possible using `service`

Comment: Thnks but why is it possible to start the same demon with two commands? By that it means that when I try to start nginx with command nginx then it is also possible to initiate a pre running deamon with systemctl start nginx. Off course it doesn't work due to port being not free but still it makes me question. thnx for reply